# Printing contents of matOfPoint2f in opencv java

Tags: java, android, opencv, arraylist

I am new to opencv java and want to print contents of matOfPoint2f on terminal. I tried using method just like to we use to print the matrix but it didn't work. So how can I print the contents of it?

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question?

Comment: Here  I want to print contents of approxCurve.                               
                                                                                                        `MatOfPoint2f matOfPoint2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
 MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
 Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contoursCopy.get(maxAreaID));
 matOfPoint2f.fromList(contoursCopy.get(maxAreaID).toList());
Imgproc.approxPolyDP(matOfPoint2f, approxCurve, Imgproc.arcLength(matOfPoint2f, true) * 0.02, true);`